# Xcodeから実行するとCGContextDrawPDFPageでエラーが発生する

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone, pdf

iOSアプリでPDFファイルの各ページをUIImageに変換する処理を作成しています。

iOS7まででは下記に示すコードで正常にPDFのページを取得・変換できているのですが、
iOS8.1で実行したところCGContextDrawPDFPageの段階で原因不明のエラーとなってしまいます。

以下が主なコードになります。

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];

CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url);


CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);
CGPDFPageRetain(pageRef);

CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, pageRect);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageRect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pageRef);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGPDFPageRelease(pageRef);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
```

<del>iOS8からCoreGraphicsでPDFの扱い方に変更があったのでしょうか？

もしよろしければ原因やヒントとなる情報をお持ちの方がいましたらご教示いただければ幸いです。</del>

なお、iOS8でも、Xcodeから実行した際にはエラーとなるものの、
ArchiveしてOTAで実機にインストールするとエラーが発生せず正常にPDFの取得・変換ができております。

つまり、
・iOS8以上
・Xcodeから実行
・一部のPDFでのみエラーとなる
という条件でエラーが発生しております。

Xcodeから実行した際と実機単体で実行した際で差分が発生する現象について、
何か知見をお持ちの方がおりましたら、
本現象と直接の関係がないことでも結構ですのでご教示いただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: Xcode 6.1.1、iOS Simulator 8.1 + iPhone 6 + iOS 8.1、OS X Yosemite 10.10.2。この環境では、エラーが出ず、UIImageViewに貼り付けて、表示できました。iOSのバージョンだけでない、なんらかの環境依存のトラブルのような気がします。より詳細な環境の説明が必要かと存じます。

Comment: さっそく動作確認までしていただきありがとうございます。

当方、以下の環境で確認しておりました。
・Xcode6.1.1
・iOS Simulator 8.1 + iPad2/iPad Air
・OSX Marverics 

お返事を受けて環境依存という観点で検証してみようと思い、
まずPDFファイルを別のものに変更したところ
あっさりと表示されてしまいました。

このことから恐らくPDF側に問題があるという可能性が高いと思われますが、
iOS7（シミュレータ、iPad Air実機）では問題なく表示できましたので、
依然として何らかの動作差分が発生していることは確かなようです。

引き続き関連すると思われる情報をお持ちの方がおられましたら、
情報をお待ちしております。

Comment: その後何の進展もない状態でしたが、Xcodeに接続しての実行とArchiveしExportしたアプリをインストールしてからの実行で動作結果に差分があることが分かりました。
今のところ、iOS8.1においてはクラッシュを引き起こすPDFがある場合はArchiveしたもので動作確認を行うことで事なきをえております。とはいえ、毎回Exportしてインストールして・・・を繰り返すのは非常に手間ですので、引き続き根本的な原因やXcode上での回避方法等模索してみようと思います。

Answer (score 2):

その後、エラー発生時のバックトレースを追ってみるなどして原因を探っていたところ、
下記の質問の回答を参考にとりあえず**エラーを抑制する方法**が分かりました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683547/avaudioplayer-throws-breakpoint-in-debug-mode

要点をかいつまむと、
C++領域の例外をスローしているので
例外ブレイクポイントを利用することでC++の例外を無視してしまおう
ということのようです。

具体的な手順としては、

1.CGContextDrawPDFPageの行を選択
[image: 手順1]

2.例外ブレイクポイントを追加
[image: 手順２]

3.監視対象？をObjective-Cのみとする
[image: 手順３]

取り急ぎこの方法でArchiveせずともテストを行えるようになりましたので報告させていただきました。
本件のように、バックトレースでlibc++絡みの例外が原因で不明なエラーが発生している場合、同様の方法で**とりあえずの抑制**ができるかもしれません。

とはいえ、根本的な原因は未だ分からない状態ですので引き続き調べてみたいと思います。
今回の発見で、どうやらC++の領域での例外が原因の可能性が高いというところまでは分かったので、そちらの方向で探ってみようと思います。